# Preventing page break in \documentclass[twocolumn]{article} after \author{}

Tags: page-breaking, titles, two-column, abstract

A page break appeared between `\author{}` and `\date{}` after I added the `\twocolumn[]` section. The `\twocolumn[]` section was added to achieve a single column abstract in the `twocolumn` document. How can I remove the page break or rewrite the single column abstract so that it doesn't cause a page break.

```
\title{TITLE}
\author{NAMES
}

\nopagebreak

\date{}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\twocolumn[
  \begin{@twocolumnfalse}
    \maketitle
    \begin{abstract}
      ABSTRACT CONTENT...
    \end{abstract}
  \end{@twocolumnfalse}
]
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You only need the single `\maketitle` within `\twocolumn[...]`:

[image]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum
\title{TITLE}
\author{NAMES}
\date{}

\begin{document}
\twocolumn[{%
  \begin{@twocolumnfalse}
    \maketitle
    \begin{abstract}
      \lipsum[1-2]
    \end{abstract}
  \end{@twocolumnfalse}
}]
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Since I've used [`lipsum`](http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum) to generate dummy text, I've had to hide the optional `\lipsum` argument `[1-2]` from that of `\twocolumn[..]` by grouping.

Alternatively, consider using the [`multicol` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/multicol). A similar output (barring some margin adjustments) is obtained using

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum,multicol}% http://ctan.org/pkg/{lipsum,multicol}
\title{TITLE}
\author{NAMES}
\date{}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
  \lipsum[1-2]
\end{abstract}

\begin{multicols}{2}
\lipsum
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with this issue for quite some time and could not find a clean solution on the internet, until I found out about this:

```
\twocolumn[ <whatever input> ]
```

The `<whatever input>` will be the single column text preceding the double column text, **without** the annoying pagebreak! And I did not face any restrictions on what I could do with this input when writing a custom titlepage including abstract with various fonts and environments.

Hope this helps!