# Two columns in a one column enviroment without page break

Tags: two-column

Is it possible to remove the page break betwean onecolumn and twocolumn? It is not possible for me to use this [help](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/91137/preventing-page-break-in-documentclasstwocolumnarticle-after-author). I have a large titlepage, a table of contents and so on. All in a one columns envirment.

At some point I want to use a two column envirment. How could I do that? I would prefer to have the one column envirment in the document class description.

Example code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, onecolumn]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\title{title}
\author{author}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\begin{abstract}
\bigskip
\twocolumn

\lipsum[1-20]
\end{document}
```

Comment: You can use package `multicol`

Comment: I tried that, but floats and marginpars are not allowed in multicols

Comment: The definition of `\twocolumn` begins with `\clearpage`, so you would have to patch this command or use another. To see the definition, you can enter `texdef -t latex -c article \twocolumn` in the terminal. (PS - You need an `\end{abstract}`, and I would put the `\twocolumn`, if you use it, before that environment.)

Comment: There are many multicolumn packages available: search CTAN.org for "columns".