# Change abstract position to top and centered

Tags: positioning, abstract

I need some help with this document on article class. I need to place the abstract in the title, centered , but It appears in the column. How can I fix this?
[image]

I want it to be placed like this 
[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Alternatively, you can look at this. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/366169/how-to-change-font-size-for-abstract-title

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Preventing page break in \documentclass\[twocolumn\]{article} after \author{}](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/91137/preventing-page-break-in-documentclasstwocolumnarticle-after-author)