# How to change font size for abstract title

Tags: fonts, fontsize, multicol

I've included `milticol` environment to my .tex file to use one column abstract in my article written using `\documentclass[10pt, twocolumn]{article}`.
But, when I use `multicols` instead `twocolumns` the abstract (title and contents) changes font size to smaller one.

How can I fix it?

```
%%%%****This is my code*****
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{multicol}
\setlength{\columnsep}{20.0pt}
 \title{some title}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
  %%this this title haven't the correct size    
\begin{abstract}
    this abstract haven't the correct size  
\end{abstract}
\begin{multicols}{2}


\section{introduction}%%this title have the correct size
some introduction.

Whatever, whatever, whatever, whatever, whatever, whatever, whatever, whatever, whatever, whatever, whatever, whatever, whatever, whatever, whatever, whatever, whatever, whatever, whatever, whatever, whatever, whatever, whatever, whatever, whatever, whatever, whatever, whatever, whatever, whatever, whatever, whatever, whatever, whatever.
\section{another section}
Whatever, whatever, whatever, whatever, whatever, whatever, whatever, whatever, whatever, whatever, whatever, whatever, whatever, whatever, whatever, whatever, whatever, whatever, whatever, whatever, whatever, whatever, whatever, whatever, whatever, whatever, whatever, whatever, whatever, whatever, whatever, whatever, whatever
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

Thanks.

Comment: The abstract is defined differently for `oneside` and `twoside` documents.

Comment: Instead of using the `abstract` environment, you can simply use `\section*{Abstract}`  instead. Or even `\begin{quote}
 {\normalfont\large\bfseries\centering Abtract\par}
this abstract haven't the correct size  
\end{quote}`.

Comment: Many thanks, it works. But how i can to modify the abstract's definition?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here it is.

Simply modify the meaning of `abstract` by inserting the following lines in your preamble:

```
\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{abstract}{%
    \if@twocolumn
      \section*{\abstractname}%
    \else %% <- here I've removed \small
      \begin{center}%
        {\bfseries \Large\abstractname\vspace{\z@}}%  %% <- here I've added \Large
      \end{center}%
      \quotation
    \fi}
    {\if@twocolumn\else\endquotation\fi}
\makeatother
```

MWE:

```
%%%%****This is my code*****
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{multicol}
\setlength{\columnsep}{20.0pt}
 \title{some title}

\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{abstract}{%
    \if@twocolumn
      \section*{\abstractname}%
    \else %% <- here I've removed \small
      \begin{center}%
        {\bfseries \Large\abstractname\vspace{\z@}}%  %% <- here I've added \Large
      \end{center}%
      \quotation
    \fi}
    {\if@twocolumn\else\endquotation\fi}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\maketitle
  %%this this title haven't the correct size
\begin{abstract}
    this abstract have the correct size
\end{abstract}
\begin{multicols}{2}


\section{introduction}%%this title have the correct size
some introduction.

Whatever, whatever, whatever, whatever, whatever, whatever, whatever, whatever, whatever, whatever, whatever, whatever, whatever, whatever, whatever, whatever, whatever, whatever, whatever, whatever, whatever, whatever, whatever, whatever, whatever, whatever, whatever, whatever, whatever, whatever, whatever, whatever, whatever, whatever.
\section{another section}
Whatever, whatever, whatever, whatever, whatever, whatever, whatever, whatever, whatever, whatever, whatever, whatever, whatever, whatever, whatever, whatever, whatever, whatever, whatever, whatever, whatever, whatever, whatever, whatever, whatever, whatever, whatever, whatever, whatever, whatever, whatever, whatever, whatever
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: If you want to get rid of the initial indent, remove `\quotation`

Answer (score 5):

It's worth examining how the `abstract` environment is defined by the `article` document class:

```
\if@titlepage
  \newenvironment{abstract}{%
      \titlepage
      \null\vfil
      \@beginparpenalty\@lowpenalty
      \begin{center}%
        \bfseries \abstractname
        \@endparpenalty\@M
      \end{center}}%
     {\par\vfil\null\endtitlepage}
\else
  \newenvironment{abstract}{%
      \if@twocolumn
        \section*{\abstractname}%
      \else
        \small
        \begin{center}%
          {\bfseries \abstractname\vspace{-.5em}\vspace{\z@}}%
        \end{center}%
        \quotation
      \fi}
      {\if@twocolumn\else\endquotation\fi}
\fi
```

In your case, since neither the `titlepage` nor the `twocolumn` options are in effect, the definition works out to be

```
 \newenvironment{abstract}{%
        \small
        \begin{center}%
          {\bfseries \abstractname\vspace{-.5em}\vspace{\z@}}%
        \end{center}%
        \quotation
      }
      {\endquotation}
```

The upshot is that if neither the `titlepage` nor the `twocolumn` options are in effect, (a) the relative font size is changed to `\small`, (b) the abstract's title (given by `\abstractname`) is centered, and (c) the body of the abstract is typeset inside a `quotation` environment; most importantly, this means that the margins inside the `abstract` environment are bit wider (and the text block is a bit narrower) than they are in the body of the text.

If you prefer the "look" that's produced if the `twocolumn` option is set, just issue the following instruction (in the preamble):

```
\renewenvironment{abstract}{\section*{\abstractname}}{}
```

Or, even more simply, just don't use the `abstract` environment at all. Instead, simply type

```
\section*{\abstractname}
```

followed by the body of the abstract.

Comment: Hi my friend. Looking forward for your 200k :-)

Comment: @karlkoeller - Thanks so much!! Hopefully, the 200k rep event will happen within a month or so. (If papiro hadn't chosen to "depart" so dramatically earlier this year, it would already have happened, some time in March...)

Answer (score 4):

Another two solutions that are not looking at the internals, but just imitate them.  One for a regular `twocolumn` (documentclass option) document, one for an imitated `twocolumn` document (using package `multicol`).

[image: gabrielsandovalAbstractTwocolumn]

```
\documentclass[10pt,twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{titling}
\title{Wombats are cool}

\renewcommand{\maketitlehookd}{%
    \begin{center}\normalfont\Large\bfseries\centering Abstract\end{center}
    \begin{quotation}
        \blindtext
    \end{quotation}
}
\begin{document}
\maketitle


\section{Introduction}
\blindtext[2]
\section{Capybara}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

Using package `multicol`, note the different margins.

[image: gabrielsandovalAbstractFakeTwocol]

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{multicol}
\setlength{\columnsep}{20.0pt}
\title{K\"urbiskernbr\"otchen}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\begin{center}\normalfont\Large\bfseries\centering Abstract\end{center}
\begin{quotation}
    \blindtext
\end{quotation}

\begin{multicols}{2}

    \section{Introduction}
    Whenever, whereever, we're meant to be together
    \blindtext
    \section{Wombat}
    \blindtext
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @Mico twocolumn and imitated twocolumn was referring to the documentclass option. Not to the abstract environment.

Comment: OK, I withdraw my comment.