# One column keywords then two column text

Tags: formatting, two-column

I will try to be as explicit as I can.

I'm producing a document with a title `\maketitle` which is fine.
Then, I have a Keyword line which is into the document and then my text.

My problem is that my 2nd column starts on the same line as the Keywords while I would like it to start at the same place then the headline.

[image: Column problem]

```
\maketitle
\begin{article}
\keywords{XX | XX | XX | XX}
\section{Headline}
\dropcap{B}la bla bla bla bla bla.
\subsection{XXX}
```

Any solution?

Comment: One solution is to use the multicol package to start and stop two column sections in one column mode. Another is to use `\twocolumn[{\maketitle \keywords...}]` and put the title and keywords into one column. Or just can just throw `\vspace{...}` into the last line of the first column.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)

Comment: Can you show us a minimal example that replicates your problem? That way we can see what your current setup is, including your `\documentclass`.

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/91137/preventing-page-break-in-documentclasstwocolumnarticle-after-author